# Connecting an HTML running Javascript to Node.js

Tags: javascript, html, node.js

for my group university project we were assigned to create a chat bot. We created it in an HTML file that has attached javascript scripts in order to change the HTML to add and get text from the user. Our latest assignment is to add NLP algorithms to the chat bot.

The best NLP algorithm we found is built using node.js and we need to have compatability between our existing HTML/Javascript code and our NLP node.js code.

What is the best way to go about this? Some references I found say that running a node.js web server is the best way but editing the HTML from that seems to be complex. Currently we cannot import our node.js modules as our HTML does not recognize it.

We are trying to run this line of code but of course it does not recognize it in the web browser yet we need to reference document, elements etc.

```
import { SentimentAnalyzer } from 'node-nlp';

const sentiment = new SentimentAnalyzer({ language: 'en' });
sentiment
    .getSentiment(userInput)
    .then(result => console.log(result));
```

Any suggestions or help would be much appreciated.

Comment: If you have some code running on the web server and some code running in the web browser then you essentially have two "applications".  The server-side code and the client-side code.  The "connection" between them is HTTP.  Your client-side code can make AJAX requests to the server and receive responses, you can open a Web Socket to the server and the server can push data to the client, etc.  Overall the question is pretty broad, it's basically the start of a web application with server-side code and client-side code.

Comment: @David That is really good to know thank you! It seems we have dug ourselves a little bit of a hole then. Your answer has helped see where we are.